# Android Matrix Scale to fit left bottom and right top

Tags: android, android-layout, scale

The Android Matrix `Matrix.ScaleToFit` contains 4 values :

> public static final Matrix.ScaleToFit CENTER
>
> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.
>
> public static final Matrix.ScaleToFit END
>
> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. END aligns the result to the right and bottom edges of dst.
>
> public static final Matrix.ScaleToFit FILL
>
> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.
>
> public static final Matrix.ScaleToFit START
>
> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top edges of dst.

I am looking for the 2 missing values for my project :

- Aligns the result to the felt and bottom edges
- Aligne the result to the right and top edges

I don't really understand why those possibilities a not in this Matrix. Do I need to use and other property instead of `android:scaleType="xxxxx"`  in my layout ?